# Delayed job; does it skip before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job, before-filter

I have a delayed job that runs perfect against a public schema in postgresql.
 
Most of my operations however are against other schemas (one for each client)

To handle different schemas I've followed the instructions and put code to switch search path, in my before_filter (in application controller).

I've noticed. That the code in the before_filter gets called perfectly during typical operations, but not at all during delayed job.

I trimmed and trimmed out everything but the simplest thing I could think of, to show entrance.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def write_to_log(text)
    File.open('c:\temp.txt', 'ab') do |f|
      f.write text + "\r\n"
      f.close
    end
  end
  before_filter :on_before_filter
  def on_before_filter
    write_to_log('hey dave');
    return if(use_token() == false);
    set_active_schema if(goto_log_in? == false);
  end
```

The code in the worker class

```
def run_job(id)
  upload = Upload.find(id)
  upload.run_job();
end
handle_asynchronously :run_job, :priority => 10, :queue => 'public'
```

Quite standard stuff?  Though the code in the job runs, the before_filter code doesn't get called.

So my question is.  Did I do something wrong?  Or more importantly, how can I do something right?

Comment: Why would a delayed job run something from your controller?

Comment: Humm.. good point..  Why would database filters be in controllers? :)  I take your point.. Where would u put the filter code?

Comment: Given current_user isn't part of model scope. It seems one has odd choices where before filter is concerned, as it should never work?

Comment: Presumably `run_job` is going to have to deal with the schema.

Comment: hardly DRY. and that means everyone who creates a job action, will have to create a schema switch.  Given there are hundreds of different jobs action in the app.  This is ripe for bugs.

Comment: You have presumably heard of "wrapping", "subclassing", "monkey patching, and similar things, right? If you have to fix hundreds of things to overcome prior shortsightedness then you have to fix hundreds of things and hopefully learn a lesson along the way.

Comment: I've not written any of the actions.. This is me planning.  I like building the tools first :)  Just don't understand how before_filter is part of controller.  Seems it's all about data :)

Comment: Oh.. what would you monkey patch? Where would have the same effect as the before_filter in the controller.  I change the search path in my controller code, so that the system knows what schema to use.  I need to do the same for DJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not recommending this approach; I'm just answering your question by providing this code.  Since you essentially want your code to run before any attempted call to the database, you can monkey patch ActiveRecord.  Add the following code to `config/initializers/active_record_monkey_patch.rb`

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool
  # create an alias for the old 'connection' method
  alias_method :old_connection, :connection

  # redefine the 'connection' method
  def connection
    # output something just to make sure the monkey patch is working
    puts "*** custom connection method called ***"

    # your custom code is here
    write_to_log('hey dave');
    return if(use_token() == false);
    set_active_schema if(goto_log_in? == false);

    # call the old 'connection' method
    old_connection
  end

end
```

You'll see your custom connection method getting called frequently now, and it will work without a controller.  You can test it by opening up a rails console and performing any database query, and you should see the "custom connection method called" message displayed several times.

Comment: the problem with that is that the job has a pile of calls to the database, and since I used the postgresql example (which uses the controller to change database) I'd have to add that to every class.

Comment: So are you saying you want your method `on_before_filter` to run automatically every time any of your class methods are invoked?

Comment: That's sort of what you need to do, to use postgres schemas. Tell the model what schema you're targeting. In the application controller it gets called before any call to your database, so it checks that the correct schema is selected, on all DB read/write. I just wanted the same when accessing the database in DJ

Comment: I updated my answer to target exactly where you want your code to run -- before every attempt to access the database.

Comment: THANKS @lee.  I'm going to use this... but for one question.  Why are you not recommending the approach?  Setting the path before each search makes sense.  If the code is as tight as I can get it, that is.

Comment: would this be called any more frequently than before_filter in the app_controller (my old approach)?

Comment: Yes it gets called quite frequently, in my tests several times per controller.  This code also lacks error handling and caching, which you may want to add.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the ActiveRecord search path for Postgres and schemas you can use a full-featured gem like apartment: https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment

You can switch to a new schema:

```
Apartment::Database.switch('database_name')
```

Regardless if you call this in an application controller request or a background job.

Comment: I don't have a problem setting the path.  Even without the gem, the problem is where does the code that does the switch live?  I don't want to put it in every one of my job actions.  Thanks for the help though.  I will take a look at the gem.